# Javascript event change

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following problem and I am new to JS. I need that every time I select an item of my "select" the event takes the value and shows me the div I need that is in "none". I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <select name="" id="mostrar">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option value="pos">Posadas</option>
                <option value="obe">Obera</option>
                <option value="eldo">Eldorado</option>
            </select>
        </form>


        <div id="posadas">Posadas</div>
        <div id="obera">Obera</div>
        <div id="eldorado">Eldorado</div>

        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
"use strict";
var pos = document.querySelector("#posadas").style.display = "none";
var obe = document.querySelector("#obera").style.display = "none";
var eldo = document.querySelector("#eldorado").style.display = "none";
var mostrar = document.querySelector("#mostrar");

mostrar.addEventListener("change", function{

if(mostrar.value == "pos") {

    pos.style.display = "block";
    obe.style.display = "none";
    eldo.style.display = "none";
    console.log(pos);

}else if(mostrar.value == "obe"){

        obe.style.display = "block";
        pos.style.display = "none";
        eldo.style.display = "none";
        console.log(obe);
}else{
        obe.style.display = "none";
        pos.style.display = "none";
        eldo.style.display = "block";
        console.log(eldo);
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `pos` and the other variables incorrectly. As you have it they are all going to be set to the value `"none"`, and not the elements themselves.

Assignments are done right to left so something like:

```
a = b.something = 3;
```

will cause both variable `a` and object `b`'s `something` property to have the value `3`.

You need to split up your lines to assign the element to the variable first then do your style change:

```
var pos = document.querySelector("#posadas");
var obe = document.querySelector("#obera");
var eldo = document.querySelector("#eldorado");
pos.style.display = "none";
obe.style.display = "none";
eldo.style.display = "none";
```